# Imagens não aparecem no site publicado no servidor web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servidor, imagem

Boa tarde pessoal,
Eu publiquei um site no servidor WEB, mas nenhuma imagem esta sendo exibida no browser.

Todas as imagens são exibidas desta forma:

```
<img src="~/imagens/logo.png"
```

Local exibe normalmente. Mas no servidor não.
Já verifiquei que as imagens existem nesse diretório.
Já tentei também modificar o código da view para exibir a URL completa ("http://dominio.com/site/imagens/logo.png"), mas também não funcionou.

O problema esta ocorrendo com css. Não exibe o site com a formatação correta.

Existe alguma configuração que deve ser feita nesse diretório dentro do servidor ou no iss para que as imagens apareçam?

Ja verifiquei na instalação do IIS, em ativar ou desativar recursos do windows, e o conteúdo estático esta habilitado.

Comment: Poderia passar o link do site ? Ou o código fonte ?

Comment: http://dev.computecnica.com.br:81/controlehoras

Answer (score 1):

altere para

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/imagens/logo.png")" />
```

Pois da você está usando um diretório virtual dentro do site principal no IIS e da forma como estava `~/` ele vai procurar na pasta Root do IIS

Comment: Obrigado @pablo vargas Não esta funcionando

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade não precisaria colocar o "til" antes do endereço, daí a busca vai ser a partir do seu diretório base, não do IIS.
Ficaria assim:

```
<img src="/imagens/logo.png" />
```